# How to calculate CR of modified beasts for druids

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, cr-calculation

I always found some creatures in MM weaker than they should be, so I would tweek them to my idea and party strength, no problem. Now my druid wants to use my modified beasts for his wild shape (circle of the moon btw.). I'm okay with that but the problem is I don't know how to determinate final CR of the creature because I've never bothered with that before, I would just change things to make encounter more interesting. Is there a table or something that determinates how much damage/AC/HP should a certain CR have/do, does multiattack alone raise CR or no? There are more things like features that grant adv/pose disadv. but they are homebrew.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this strikes me as a "read the rules to me" sort of question.

Comment: That's usually not a close reason just a downvote reason ("does not show any research effort") see https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/what-do-we-do-with-read-the-book-to-me-questions.

Answer (score 16):

Rules for calculating a monster's CR can be found starting on page 273 of the DMG.

Things that affect a creature's CR include:

- Armour Class
- Hit Points
- Damage vulnerabilities, resistances, and immunities
- Attack bonuses
- Damage output
- Save DCs
- etc.